# Combining two queries to compare different columns

Tags: postgis, postgresql

Suppose I have a table

```
create table positions
(
 location geography,
 property1 int,
 property2 varchar
);
```

I can do the following queries:

```
select property2 from positions 
  where st_dwithin(POINT, location, dmax) and not st_dwithin(POINT, location, dmin);

select property2 from positions where st_dwithin(POINT, location, dIgnore);
```

I want to

```
select * from positions 
  where [results of query1 except where results of query1 have property1 = property1 of the results of query2]
```

I have tried various things (which I will spare you the trouble of reading, because they all resulted in syntax errors). How would I do this query?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly (you probably means property1 in query2), you can have multiple properties in your query2, so you could, using CTE for clarity, do things like that (untested):

```
WITH query1 as (
    select * from positions 
        where st_dwithin(POINT, location, dmax) and not st_dwithin(POINT, location, dmin)
), query2 as (
    select DISTINCT ON (property1) property_ignored, TRUE as check_field from positions where st_dwithin(POINT, location, dIgnore)
)
select * from query1 
    left join query2 on query1.property1=query2.property_ignored
    where check_field IS NULL
```

That way you left join with your properties that you want to ignore, and in the case the property is not in the query2 the check_field should be null. You could also do the same with a more classical `WHERE property2 NOT IN property_ignored` without the left join.